# Wildfly 26.1.3 memory consumption

Tags: memory, wildfly, wildfly-26

Recently I've upgraded a web application running on RedHat Enterprise AP 7.1 to Wildfly 26.1.3, on top Kubernetes environment.

First consideration is that Wildfly 26.1.3 memory consumption is higher than Redhat 7.1, approx 3.0-3.5GB vs 2.0-2.5GB.

Second consideration is that Wildfly 26.1.3 doesn't seem free memory, specially upon low load (at the night), while RedHat 7.1 does. So for example a couple of Kubernetes pods can reach the memory limit, 5GB, and never free memory. I tried to capture an heap dump, but it doesn't contain anything worthy of note. Does anybody found something similar? Is it normal?

[image: Wildfly 26.1.3 memory consumption]

Thank you very much!

Comment: WildFly itself won't free memory. That is up to the JVM. Red Hat EAP 7.1 is quite a bit older than WildFly 26.1.3.Final, but it's still based on WildFly. While there are probably new subsystems and modules, it shouldn't be taking much more memory.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I've noted that Redhat EAP 7.1 JVM does free memory over night; while most recent Wildfly JVM does not.